# Unable to catch 403 in try-catch during fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, put, http-status-code-403, fetch-api

I'm making a put request using ReactJS, however, when I put in the wrong email/password combination, I get this logged on Chrome, even though I'm trying to catch all errors and show them in `errorDiv`:

[image]

```js
async connect(event) {
  try {
    const userObject = {
      username: this.state.userName,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    if (!userObject.username || !userObject.password) {
      throw Error('The username/password is empty.');
    }
    let response = await fetch(('someurl.com'), {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject)
    });
    let resJSON = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(resJSON.message);
    }
    console.info(resJSON.message);
    console.info(resJSON.message.auth_token);
    window.location = "/ledger/home";
  } catch (e) {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = e;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code is ok. The problem cannot be replicated, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pb51rz

Answer (score 10):

As per the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful), `fetch` will throw only when a network error is encountered.
`404` (or `403`) are not a network error.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.
>
> a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example. An accurate check for a successful fetch() would include checking that the promise resolved, then checking that the Response.ok property has a value of true

Comment: So there is no way I can catch this and display it to the user rather than it creating a log automatically?

Answer (score 7):

I completely agree with @Sagiv, but there is a quick workaround to do that, although it is not a suggested way.
Inside of try or promise.then(), you need to do this check.

```
const res = await fetch();
console.log(res);    // You can see the response status here by doing res.status
```

So, by some simple checks it is possible to resolve or reject a promise. For e.g. in your case

```js
async connect(event) {
  try {
    const userObject = {
      username: this.state.userName,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    if (!userObject.username || !userObject.password) {
      throw Error('The username/password is empty.');
    }
    let response = await fetch('someurl.com', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject)
    });
    if (response.status === 403) throw new Error('403 is unacceptable for me!');
    let resJSON = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error(resJSON.message);
    }
    console.info(resJSON.message);
    console.info(resJSON.message.auth_token);
    window.location = '/ledger/home';
  } catch (e) {
    document.getElementById('errorDiv').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('errorDiv').innerHTML = e;
  }
}
```

I strongly recommend using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). For the fetch issue, you can refer to this [link](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you throw Error and then catch part of your code does not execute. Try this:

```
async connect(event) {
  try {
    const userObject = {
      username: this.state.userName,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    if (!userObject.username || !userObject.password) {
      throw Error('The username/password is empty.');
    }
    let response = await fetch(('someurl.com'), {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject)
    }).then(response => {
       response.json();
       console.info(resJSON.message);
       console.info(resJSON.message.auth_token);
       window.location = "/ledger/home";
    }).catch(e => {
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("errorDiv").innerHTML = e;
  })
}
```

Comment: Do I add another catch after the last line? Since the .catch is inside the try itself.