# Why 500 error throws runtime exception and is not handled by promise catch block

Tags: javascript, fetch

I have an api call, and server return 500 error, I expect it to be handled in Promise but I get runtime error `TypeError: Failed to fetch` and stack trace so I am not able to retrieve status code. Is there way to get [Response Instanse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response#instance_properties) from api request with status field and not a runtime error

```js
try {
      window.fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body,
        }).then((res) => { 
                // I expect response to be there
        }, (rej) => {
                // Or there
        });
    } catch (e) {
      // When server replies with 500 error it's handled here and not in promise block
    }
```

Comment: fetch is async. By the time you get a response, you're already out of the try catch.

Comment: The code provided doesn't throw an error for the try to catch? 500 errors will be returned in the then.

Comment: Yes, I expect errors to be in then, but for some reason fetch throws runtime error. In Network it's said that api returned 500. And I'm wondering why fetch failes

Comment: what should the fetch return if the server answers with a 500? For me it's absolutely clear that the fetch will fail. btw you do not need the try. You can also directly add a .catch() to the fetch. Maybe this would make it clearer for you

Comment: With this code, and the server returning a 500 error, it will return the response inside the `then`. I think [fetch only throws when a network error is encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52458417/989920)

Comment: `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()/text()).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.error(err))` could you try this way? It should log your response this way.

Answer (score 1):

Because `fetch` is asynchronous, the little time it takes to fetch and resolve/reject will take the code out of the try/catch block. To keep the code inside the try/catch, you need to use the `await` keyword:

```js
(async () => {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    // Code here catches the error
  } finally {
    if(response) {
      // Do something with the response
    }
  }
})()
```